# Anonymous recursion - any way to replace javascript 'arguments.callee' to other symol such as 'SELF'?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I want to replace js `arguments.callee` to another symbol like **SELF**.

Is it possible?

Macro approach such as [sweetjs](http://sweetjs.org/) is the only way?

---

**EDIT**

Thanks a lot for inputs:

I understand `arguments.callee` is prohibited in StrictMode.

To make things clear, I present my code: **anonymous recursion**

```
var factorial = function (n)
{
    return n ? n * arguments.callee(n - 1) : 1;
};
console.log( factorial(10) );  //3628800
```

and now

```
var SELF = function (val)
{
    return arguments.callee(val);
}
var factorial = function (n)
{
    return n ? n * SELF(n - 1) : 1;
};
console.log( factorial(10) );
```

gives an error

```
var SELF = function (val)
                    ^
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Also, I know there's a way for **anonymous recursion** not to use `arguments.callee`, instead to use **Y-Combinator**.

But, `arguments.callee` cannot be replaced by such a thing correct?
In **Y-Combinator** Scenario, the code must be

```
var f = function(f) {
           return function(n){
              return n ? n * f(n - 1) : 1;
           }
        }
```

The nest becomes deeper to define factorial, etc. which I am not willing to...

---

**EDIT2**

after a short period of time, a fine article hits.

[Anonymous recursion in 6 lines of Javascript](http://am.aurlien.net/post/2810658101/z-combinator)

The author Arne Martin calls **z-combinator**:

```
var Z = function(func)
{
    var f = function ()
    {
        return func.apply(null, [f].concat([].slice.apply(arguments)));
    };
    return f;
}

var factorial = function (f, n)
{
    return n ? n * f(n - 1) : 1;
}

console.log(  Z(factorial)(10) );
```

This method perfectly fills my needs, and also since it doesn't require 'arguments.callee', we don't worry about strict mode!

Comment: You can use a named function expression and use that name inside.

Comment: Couldn't you just use `var SELF = arguments.callee;` or am I missing something here.

Comment: Just a heads-up: using `arguments.callee` will throw a `TypeError` under strict mode.

Comment: Thanks, I add some additional explanation ->EDIT

Comment: I solved the anonymous function issue with the Z-combinator you pointed out but some issues arises from its use. Fi: The this reference is overwrote in every step the recursive function goes down. There are a way to keep the top level this untouchable without having to pass it as an additional function argument? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18194289/javascript-this-overwriting-in-z-combinator-and-every-other-recursive-function

Answer (score 2):

if you do not want to use strict mode, and don't mind using global variables and deprecated features, you can add custom read-only "keywords" to most modern JS implementations:

```
Object.defineProperty(
 self, 
 "SELF", 
 {get:function(){return arguments.callee.caller;} //!! deprecated feature in use!!
});


function demo(a,b){
  alert(SELF);
}

function someOtherFunction(a,b){
  alert(SELF);
}



demo();
someOtherFunction();
```

this is cool and all, but there are more robust and modern ways of doing this, namely using the function's name:

```
function someAdditionalFunction(a,b){
  alert(someAdditionalFunction);
}
```

using the name lets you grab the same info as the "SELF" getter above, and works in strict mode and without global variables. The one downside to using function names is that you can't re-use the same symbol over and over, unless you use exclusively named function expressions, and give your functions and internal name of self:

```
var demo=function SELF(a,b){
  alert(SELF);
};

var someOtherFunction=function SELF(a,b){
  alert(SELF);
};

demo();
someOtherFunction();
```

Comment: Be very careful with named function expressions—IE makes them global variables.

Comment: Wait, for real? Even today?

Comment: A quick search says at least IE8. No clue about IE9+.

Comment: Today, this is only an issue with IE8 and below.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i've done in the past for a self referencing functions where I don't want to use `arguments.callee`. Just put a name in the function definition:

```
var factorial = function factorialcallee(n)
{
    return n ? n * factorialcallee(n - 1) : 1;
};
console.log( factorial(10) );  //3628800
```