# Javascript 'this' overwriting in Z combinator and every other recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursion, this, anonymous-function

**Background:**

I have a recursive function implemented by a **Z-combinator** as is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17645356/anonymous-recursion-any-way-to-replace-javascript-arguments-callee-to-other) and [here](http://am.aurlien.net/post/2810658101/z-combinator) so it makes no use of `arguments.callee` since it will be deprecated in upcoming **ES6**.

**Issue**

The main issue with the **Z-combinator** and all recursive anonymous functions I've seen so far is that they updates de `this` value to the inner function scope (the self-returned at the `return` clause), so the `this` that references the top level is lost, and I want to maintain it through all the inner functions.

Is there a way to maintain the top level `this` without passing it as an additional function argument, which is the most obvious way to get rid of this issue but is not as clean as I want?

**EDIT:**

Right now I solve the issue by passing the top `this` reference to the **Z-combinator** like this:

```
Co.Utilities.Z(this.createHTMLFromLOM)(this.LOM, this);
```

in the recursive function I return the same function by passing the top this value like this:

```
function createHTMLFromLOM(callee:any, LOM_section:LOM, self:any):void {
    /* Some other code. */
    return callee(LOM_section.children[widget], self);
}
```

This is my **Z-combinator** definition:

```
function Z(func:any):any {
        var f = function () {
            return func.apply(null, [f].concat([].slice.apply(arguments)));
        };
         return f;
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following :

`var me = this;`

and the pass `me` as an argument to the Z Combinator.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what you said is how I do that right now. I will update the question to point that. Have you another way to do that?

Comment: Could you post an exact code sample rather than links to the Z Combinator pattern please ? It would be easier to debug code this way.

Comment: You could try `return func.apply(null, [f].concat([].slice.call(arguments, this)));` but I'm not really sure that would help / work.

Comment: That didn't worked :( well, I will accept your answer as correct and vote it up since it was the same I was doing it for reference. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't help. :S

Comment: Don't say that! You helped me a lot by confirm my solution! :D